# Encountering ValueError when building a web scraper

Tags: python, excel, list, web-scraping, html-table

The list that I have scraped from the website has 6 elements and the for loop considers 6 elements as well, but when I try to execute the program I get a ValueError (expected 6). this is really confusing me and im at the end of my rope! hope people much smarter than me can help me out on this one!
Thanks

````
import bs4 as bs
import xlsxwriter as xl
y = 0
revenue = 0
row = 0
col = 0
r = requests.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/britanniaindustries/consolidated-profit-lossVI/BI')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

table = soup.find(class_='mctable1').find_all('tr')[1:]
elem = table
for row in elem:
    y += 1
    cell = [i.text for i in row.find_all('td')]
    if y == 8:
        revenue = cell

# upon printing revenue at this point I get : ['Total Revenue', '13,449.07', '11,878.95', '11,261.12', '10,080.36', '9,204.63', '\xa0']

workbook = xl.Workbook('investment data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for head, twentyone, twenty, nineteen, eighteen, rubbish in revenue:
    worksheet.write(row, col, head)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, twentyone)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, twenty)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, nineteen)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 4, eighteen)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 5, rubbish)

workbook.close() ```
````

Comment: Just skipping over the code: Did you make sure, that revenue actuall contains a list? I see, that `revenue = cell` is only assigned if some condition is met. The easiest explanation would be, that this condition is never met, and you try to access 6 elements in `revenue = 0`

Comment: @sagre when I comment out all the xlwriter stuff and just print out the revenue after the first for loop I do get a list with the relevant info! so that must mean the list is properly defined, right?

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the content of `revenue` right before the for loop?

Comment: @Sagre edited to add the list in!

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get why you want to use a for loop here? A for loop would be useful, if you want to process each element of the list seperatly. `for a in list` assignes a to each element of your list one after another, which would be `Total Revenue:` on the first iteration, `13,449.07` on the second one, and so on. `for a,b in list` assumes, that you list contains lists with two elements. However this is not the case, since you have a simple list.

One variant which would be more useful here:

```
for index,entry in enumerate(revenue):
    worksheet.write(row, col + index, entry)
```

`enumerate(list)` gives you the current index and list member (therefore you dont need to hardcode `col+1`) and you properly iterate over your revenue list

What you tried to do, was to access each element of the list in a single for loop iteration. So you either access each element one after another, as shown above, or you remove the for loop and just write to the worksheet:

```
worksheet.write(row, col, revenue[0])
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, revenue[1])
worksheet.write(row, col + 2, revenue[2])
worksheet.write(row, col + 3, revenue[3])
worksheet.write(row, col + 4, revenue[4])
worksheet.write(row, col + 5, revenue[5])
```

However, this would be very very unelegant

Comment: Ahhh I see! I'm quite new to this whole buisiness so the for loop was my first intuition but your idea makes much more sense!
However, when I try to use this snippet in my code I get this error : TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tag' what should I do?
(sorry for expecting you to write this code for me! I'm just a newbie and I'm very grateful for your help!)

Comment: Probably a problem with the arguments to `worksheet.write(`. Can you post the complete error message together with your updated code, best as an edit to your question?